# Using one set of Bluetooth peripherals for multiple devices

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

On my desk I have three computers.

One laptop for my personal use, one laptop for work and a desktop I use occasionally to watch movies or play a game.

Here is my problem: I want to use one Bluetooth keyboard & one Bluetooth mouse to connect to all of them. Only one at a time.

Right now my peripherals only 'remember' the last paired device. So if I boot up another laptop. I first have to go into Windows settings, make my peripherals discoverable, and reconnect them as if they were completely unknown. They appear in the list as previously connected devices, but they don|t connect, even though they aren't connected to another device. Using the desktop is even worse. I have to use a USB keyboard and mouse to even get to the settings app, where I can connect my Bluetooth peripherals. So to put it simply: My current setup is a mess!

Ideally, I would start a laptop/desktop and my peripherals would automatically connect to the next 'known' device if they're currently unpaired. Similar to what my wired display does.

How can I do this?

---

My peripherals:
Keryboard: Microsoft Surface Keyboard

Mouse: Microsoft Surface Mouse

Comment: The problem with your Bluetooth devices is that they stores "Link key" (and probably MAC) or last paired device. So next time you want to change your PC you have to "repair" your peripheral. The only solution is to write very simple too that will try to connect to your peripheral on boot (pair with it and then connect). Its not too hard but needs some programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you cant.  Standard Bluetooth keyboards are designed to connect to a single host.  I believe Bluetooth mice are the same. 
 Connecting to multiple hosts would be a security risk.

That doesnt mean you cant do it.  However, you would need to buy a new keyboard and mouse.  Logitech sells Bluetooth [keyboards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LZAK8MM) and [mice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071VK5KXN) that can connect to multiple Bluetooth hosts.  You can search for others.

Another possibility would be to use software.  [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) has been around for ages and allows one set of keyboard and mouse to control multiple computers.  I have used it in the past and can say it works.  However, I have not used it recently.

Comment: Does Synergy work, when I just use one device at a time?

Comment: @jonhue Interesting, im genuinely surprised there are no videos on the website showing it in use. It works similarly to multimonitors in windows, you just move the mouse to the next screen, except it  is the next pc.  When the mouse is there, the keyboard is active on that computer.

Comment: Ah, I think you misunderstood me. By only using one device at a time, I mean that all other devices are powered off/sleeping. So my issue is only with shutting one device down, booting another device up and taking keyboard and mouse with me.

Answer (score 0):

There are third-party tools that allow you to control several computers using
one keyboard and one mouse and one monitor from one computer,
meaning that you can stay on one computer but switch to the others,
leaving your Bluetooth devices paired with that one computer.

Here are some tools I know of (but haven't tested any of them) :

- [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/) (free)
- [Microsoft Garage Mouse without Borders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460) (free)
- [Share Mouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/)
  (limited free version or starting at $29.95)
- [Stardock Multiplicity KVM Pro](https://www.stardock.com/products/multiplicity/)
  (trialware, $39.99)
- [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy)
  (trialware, starting from $29)
- [Across](http://www.acrosscenter.com/) (yearly license)

Comment: [Logitech Flow](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/options) is free software that works like Synergy which allows you to use a single keyboard and mouse set seamlessly across 2+ devices/screens. It works on macOS and Windows. It's super nice to have with a mouse like the M590 which is silent and has both a bluetooth receiver built-in and a USB unified receiver. Switching between devices only requires a quick press of a button behind the scroll wheel that's effortless to activate.